# How to use custom fonts in React for Web Apps (without additional CSS file)?

Tags: reactjs, fonts, font-face, font-family

How can I use custom fonts with React for Web Apps? I do not want to use a CSS file but keep everything in the Component JS file.

I have tried everything and nothing seams to work or at least they are not consistent (sometimes they work sometimes they do not load on ipads or certain computers)?

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: without css is not possible because in some place you need to specify which font you'll use.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried doing something like this and it worked for me
Add a CDN for fonts if you are using google fonts or something like:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i" rel="stylesheet">
```

and then in your CSS use the font-family property and there enter the font you are trying to access from google fonts and it will be working fine. If you want to change the thickness then use the font-weight to manage that.